# How do I call a Scala Object method using reflection?

Tags: reflection, scala, object

say, I have the following:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def someMethod: String;
}

object SomeObject extends SomeTrait {
  def someMethod = "something";
}
```

I would like to call "someMethod" using reflection as I have the object name as a String.
Something like:

```
val objectName = "SomeObject"  
val someTrait:SomeTrait = ???.asInstanceOf[SomeTrait]  
someTrait.someMethod
```

or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 25):

```
def companion[T](name : String)(implicit man: Manifest[T]) : T = 
    Class.forName(name + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(man.erasure).asInstanceOf[T]

val result = companion[SomeTrait]("SomeObject").someMethod
```

Comment: This is even better. Thanks Thomas.

Comment: Do you need the manifest? I found that `Class.forName(name + "$").getField("MODULE$").get(null)` is sufficient. This is allowed for static fields.

Comment: How does it translate in 2.10 with reflection?

Comment: Using Scala 2.10.2, my code threw an exception on `Class.forName(name + "$").getField("MODULE$")`

Comment: @Thomas Jung , what is the "$" here , what it refer too , sorry me new to scala.

Answer (score 20):

Since scala 2.10, we can use the reflection of Module:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val module = runtimeMirror.staticModule("SomeObject")
val obj = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)
val someTrait:SomeTrait = obj.instance.asInstanceOf[SomeTrait]  
someTrait.someMethod
```

Answer (score 15):

For classes, this can be done pretty easily using the standard java reflection classOf method. For Scala objects, it is a bit more work, but it still can be done:

```
trait SomeTrait { def someMethod: String}
object SomeObject extends SomeTrait { def someMethod = "something"}

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait { def someMethod = "something"}

object Main {
 def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val someClassTrait:SomeTrait = Class.forName("SomeClass").newInstance().asInstanceOf[SomeTrait]
    println("calling someClassTrait: " + someClassTrait.someMethod)
    val objectName = "SomeObject$"
    val cons = Class.forName(objectName).getDeclaredConstructors(); 
    cons(0).setAccessible(true);
    val someObjectTrait:SomeTrait = cons(0).newInstance().asInstanceOf[SomeTrait]
    println("calling someObjectTrait: " + someObjectTrait.someMethod)
  }
}

//prints:
calling someClassTrait: something
calling someObjectTrait: something
```

Comment: I think it does break the expectation of clients of a companion (singleton) object if you create new instances of it.

Comment: Arjan - thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Thomas - That's true. But you could always wrap the code in an object factory and provide the singleton behavior yourself.