# How to call the object method (not class method) using reflection in scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I'd like to call the object main method using reflection in scala. But it did not works, the following 2 lines of code will through exception that I could not create the object using reflection.

```
val clazz = Class.forName(job.runnerClass)
val runnerClass = clazz.newInstance()
```

Comment: Got the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039822/how-do-i-call-a-scala-object-method-using-reflection?rq=1

Comment: Feel free to delete your own question if it's a duplicate of another. This saves reviewers work determining if it's a duplicate and closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have do use an $ at the end of your class name, because scala objects always end with $.
You can then find the object instance in a field called MODULE$

```
val class = Class.forName(name)
val objectInstance = class.getField("MODULE$").get(class).asInstanceOf[YOURCLASSTYPE]
```