# Call scala method from object dynamically

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a scala case class and object like below,

```
case class User(userId: Long, UserName: String, ts: Timestamp)

object User {

  def getRdd(rdd: RDD[JsValue], type : String): RDD[User] = {

    val rdd1: RDD[User] = rdd.map(doc => processEvent(doc))
      .filter(event => event._1.equals(rddType)).map(event => {
      User.get_class_obj(event)
    })
    rdd1
  } 

}
```

I want to call "getRdd" method of User Object from another object without creating instance of object/class. like below,

```
val object_name = "com.User"
val method_name = "getRdd"
```

I tried,

```
val no = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(no)


Class.forName(object_name).getDeclaredMethod(method_name).invoke(rdd)
```

but fails with nosuchmethod error. I have gone through answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039822/how-do-i-call-a-scala-object-method-using-reflection) but I don't want to create multiple instances every time. Is it possible to do it in one-liner.

Comment: Can you describe your use case for this? In Scala, reflection is rarely the best way to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with dollar sign

```
val object_name = "com.User$"
```

if object `User` is in package `com`.

From Java reflection point of view `User` is a class and `User$` is its companion object.

You should also specify classes of arguments

```
Class.forName("com.User$").getDeclaredMethod("getRdd", classOf[RDD[_]], classOf[String])
```

Comment: I tried running Class.forName(object_name + "$").getDeclaredMethod(method_name).invoke(rdd) but still same. Not able to find such method. Can you share code snippet? That would be helpful to understand.

Comment: @NachiketKate You should also specify types of arguments `Class.forName("com.User$").getDeclaredMethod("getRdd", classOf[RDD[JsValue]], classOf[String])`